# How to add a Password to User Account if previously it set to "Log In Without Password"

Tags: password, users

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and some time ago I opened User Accounts with Administrator Privilage and I made change as "LOG IN WITHOUT PASSWORD" and now I want to add a password to My User Account. But I can not unlock the user account dialog, because it is asking for password and if it left blank still it's not opening!
Please Help Me to solve My Problem!

Comment: It should have had you make a password on the same screen where you said to log in without one. Use that password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution when I encountered this before.

1. Open up Terminal and type in `passwd`.
2. Enter a new password (For a strong password make sure it has capitals, more than 8 characters and numbers) and press enter.
3. Retype your new password and press enter.

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal, and enter "passwd" ... this will change the password for the current user. If you want to change an other users password, you will need to enter "sudo passwd", because then you need to run passwd with root privileges.

Comment: Hey Really Thank You Very Much for Ur Reply and for giving time to answer My Question! Really Thanks Again!

Answer (score 3):

just open a terminal and write `passwd` It will ask for the new password if it was blank previously or ask for the old password if it was not blank.

Comment: Hey Really Thank You Very Much for Ur Reply and for giving time to answer My Question! Really Thanks Again!