# I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have problems with the password

Tags: password-recovery

In the installation process I choose to boot without a password (automatically).It works fine. But when I try to install software over the Software-Center I'm beeing asked for a password. But I have no password. What can I do?

Comment: possible your answer is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121018/how-to-add-a-password-to-user-account-if-previously-it-set-to-log-in-without-pa)

Answer (score 0):

try to recover the password through the root access,

here are the links

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

[Lost Password - Ubuntu official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a password by going into the recovery mode, dropping to a root shell and running "passwd [username]" then typing in a new password and confirming it. You should then be able to reboot and it should still login automatically but to launch admin tools and install stuff you will need to enter that password.